# What is the proper way to loop through TPL Dataflow blocks?

Tags: c#, loops, task-parallel-library, job-scheduling, tpl-dataflow

I read somewhere that TPL Dataflow blocks can be looped, but I have not seen a clear example of how one would go about this.  My idea is the following but I am not sure if I am breaking some rules or if there is simply a better way?

1) I will fill a concurrent job queue with a 'job' object (object will have list of command(s), loop value)

2) the queue send the job to a transformation block which will see what the first command should be and use a broadcast block to send a message to all other transformation blocks

3) if a transformation block linked to the broadcast block sees the message is intended for it, it will do the transformation on the job object. On completion it will link to 2nd broadcast block.

4) the 2nd broadcast block will send a message which will be used by other blocks to update the GUI, and update a log file

5) the 2nd broadcast block will also send a message to a transformation block whose sole purpose will be to check the job object to see if there are any commands left in it's list. If so, this block will re-add the job object to the main job queue but not before it replaces the command that it just finished with the next command. The job object could also have a loop counter property that would be decremented before the job is re-added to the queue.

In other words, what I want to do in real-life:  I have an XML file (job object) that contains test parameters including what tests to run and how many times the test should be repeated (if at all). The test station could run tests on anywhere from 1 to 16 separate units, with each unit running it's own unique test(s). I am choosing the TPL dataflow method because these tests all need to be able to be run concurrently on seperate threads, and units swapped in and out by asynchronous humans. The actions/commands are fairly simple;  one is to just run a bunch of measurements, another action is to heat-up a test unit to a specific temperature for 'x' number of minutes, a power down command (just for the specific unit, not all units), and so on.  The heating task is just one command, followed by a long wait where it will do nothing.

** Example Jobs (started on different days) **

Unit 7:  measure,  heat 30 minutes, measure, powerdown

unit 10: measure, heat for 500 minutes, repeat these two commands 10 times,  powerdown (at end of loop)

unit 3:  measure,  powerdown

unit 5:  measure every 30 minutes for 1 day, heat for 7 days, measure, powerdown.

Comment: just send to the original block, or link back to with the appropriate options

Comment: @TheGeneral   so something as basic as this:                                                    
    if (LoopCounter <1 )
         TransformationBlock1.LinkTo(EndBlock, linkOptions);
    else
     TransformationBlock1.LinkTo(JobQueue, linkOptions);

Comment: I honestly haven't read the full question, however, you can just send/post back to the original block, You can also use the LinkTo plumbing as well, but you will have to use the predicate `.LinkTo(Block, data.LoopCounter <1 );` and there for that data must exist in the data your a piping